# HTTPS Giving Segfault in cpp-httplib

Tags: c++, https

I'm trying to do some HTTP(**S**) requests with cpp-httplib. Why does

```
#include <iostream>
#include "httplib.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hi" << endl;

    auto res = httplib::Client("http://stackoverflow.com").Get("/");
    cout << res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

print

```
hi
0x5605c058db50
```

(OK), but

```
#include <iostream>
#include "httplib.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hi" << endl;

    auto res = httplib::Client("https://stackoverflow.com").Get("/");
    cout << res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(same code, just changed `http` to `https`)

```
hi
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

?

GDB `backtrace` gives me this after the segfault:

```
#0  0x000055555555eee8 in httplib::ClientImpl::Socket::is_open (this=0x50) at /home/viktor/delayWatcher/cpp-fetcher/libs/httplib.h:822
#1  0x0000555555569a20 in httplib::ClientImpl::send (this=0x0, req=..., res=...) at /home/viktor/delayWatcher/cpp-fetcher/libs/httplib.h:4579
#2  0x000055555556bb8b in httplib::ClientImpl::Get(char const*, std::multimap<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, httplib::detail::ci, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&, std::function<bool (unsigned long, unsigned long)>) (this=0x0, path=0x5555555bc887 "/", headers=std::multimap with 0 elements, progress=...) at /home/viktor/delayWatcher/cpp-fetcher/libs/httplib.h:4980
#3  0x000055555556ba1d in httplib::ClientImpl::Get (this=0x0, path=0x5555555bc887 "/") at /home/viktor/delayWatcher/cpp-fetcher/libs/httplib.h:4958
#4  0x000055555556c345 in httplib::Client::Get (this=0x7fffffffe320, path=0x5555555bc887 "/") at /home/viktor/delayWatcher/cpp-fetcher/libs/httplib.h:6015
#5  0x000055555555d767 in main () at /home/viktor/delayWatcher/cpp-fetcher/fetcher/main.cpp:11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the README on [cpp-httplib github](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/blob/master/README.md):

- add `#define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT`,
- link `libssl` and `libcrypto`.

So the code would be so:

```
#include <iostream>

#define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT

#include "httplib.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hi" << endl;

    auto res = httplib::Client("https://stackoverflow.com").Get("/");
    cout << res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and in my case running `g++` with `-lssl -lcrypto` at the end.

What I tried and but was (maybe obviously?) wrong: the `#define` needs to go before `#include "httplib.h"`.

```
// WRONG order, still segfault
#include "httplib.h"

#define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT
```